# Tikz, Grid numbering, repeating structures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}%
\usepackage[np,autolanguage]{numprint}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw[step=1cm,black,thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    %\foreach \x in {0, 1,...,5} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,-0.2) {0.0}; }
    %\foreach \y in {0, 1,...,5} { \node [anchor=east] at (-0.2,\y) {\y}; }
    \node at (-0.5,0) {0.0};
    \node at (-0.5,1) {0.2};
    \node at (-0.5,2) {0.4};
    \node at (-0.5,3) {0.6};
    \node at (-0.5,4) {0.8};
    \node at (-0.5,5) {1.0};
    \node at (0,-0.5) {0.0};
    \node at (1,-0.5) {0.2};
    \node at (2,-0.5) {0.4};
    \node at (3,-0.5) {0.6};
    \node at (4,-0.5) {0.8};
    \node at (5,-0.5) {1.0};
    \draw [fill=black, thin] (0.5,2.5) circle [radius=0.05];
    \draw [fill=black, thin] (1.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.05];
    \draw [fill=black, thin] (2.5,4.5) circle [radius=0.05];
    \draw [fill=black, thin] (3.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.05];
    \draw [fill=black, thin] (4.5,3.5) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Please tell me there is a better way to number the grids (not numbering individual node) and drawing multiple circles in one go!

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want simple foreachs for everything? The same as in your code can be done with

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1cm,black,thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \foreach \xtick in {0,...,5} {\pgfmathsetmacro\result{\xtick * .2} \node at (\xtick,-0.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}; }
    \foreach \ytick in {0,...,5} {\pgfmathsetmacro\result{\ytick * .2} \node at (-.5,\ytick) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}}; }
    \foreach \x/\y in {.5/2.5, 1.5/.5, 2.5/4.5, 3.5/1.5, 4.5/3.5}{\draw [fill=black, thin] (\x,\y) circle [radius=0.05];}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want something more clever, you have to explain the technique you want to show here.

Nodes can be placed as `below` and `left` as well. No hard coding needed.

---

If you are going to plot more data, you should go for `pgfplots` of course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ,x=5cm,y=5cm
        ,grid=major
        ,major grid style={thick,black}
        ,xmin=0, xmax=1
        ,ymin=0, ymax=1
        ]
    \addplot[black, mark=*, only marks] table {
        .1 .5 
        .3 .1
        .5 .9
        .7 .3
        .9 .7 
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi thank you. That answers my question! Thank you! I am not sure what can be more clever/concise than this?! :)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi You can replace the first three lines of the first solution by this single path `\draw grid(5,5)foreach~in{0,.2,...,1}{(5*~,-.5)node{\pgfmathprintnumber{~}}(-.5,5*~)node{\pgfmathprintnumber{~}}};`

Comment: @Kpym Please feel free to edit or add whatever you like. Thank you.